# Ubuntu cordova cannot run without root

Tags: cordova, ubuntu

I tried running

```
npm install -g cordova
```

but it cannot install it, must have "sudo" before it. This lead to when I want to add a new project I have to run

```
sudo cordova create
```

But it cannot run, it said ANDROID_HOME is not set. When I run

```
sudo -i
```

to run with root, it can run find. I have edit .bashrc for /root/ and /home/myUser/

So, how can I install cordova with

```
npm install -g cordova
```

?

Comment: After you do the install `sudo chown -R {your_user_name} /path/to/where/cordova/installed` This will remove the need for `sudo` when running cordova commands

Comment: @DawsonLoudon thank you, after that I have to sudo chown -R {my_user_name} /home/{my_user_name} too to make it work. Kinda take a headache. You're my savior.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked. I will add it as an answer with your additional input as well for others to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to change the owner of the path where cordova is installed and possibly change the owner of the path you will be building in.

For cordova:

```
sudo chown -R {your_user_name} /path/to/where/cordova/installed
```

And then the same on the path where your app projects will be:

```
sudo chown -R {your_user_name} /path/to/app/project
```

Comment: actually, I have to sudo chown my home path to make it work not project path :D

Comment: Some people have an issue with doing that to the entire directory, so I just included the project path, but yeah I do the home dir as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ANDROID_HOME` is not set in your root's environment variables.
Either
append `ANDROID_HOME="Path to your sdk"`  to  `/root/.bashrc`
or
use `sudo -E` instead of `sudo` which will use your environment variables.
Remember second option assumes that you have `ANDROID_HOME` set in your `bashrc`.

Comment: I have set the ANDROID_HOME in /root/, and it's working with root. The problem is I wanna run it without root. 
I have made it work with Dawson way.
Thank you so much for yout effort :)

Comment: You need to install cordova without sudo (as regular user).Earlier you could not install it without sudo because the directory in which you are installing does not have write permission for you. You need to change permissions. As **Dawson Loudon** mentioned first get ownership of that directory using **chown** and then see if you have write permission if no then change permission using **chmod**